# jdbc:mysql:replication causes Unknown column in 'field list' exception at runtime

Tags: jboss, jndi, jboss5.x, database-replication, master-slave

I am using JBOSS EAP 5.1
want to implement Master/slave mechanism.
xyz-mysql-ds.xml         (for ex. customer db)
xyz-mysql-ds.common.xml (for common db)

I have added master/slave ip in xyz-mysql-ds.xml

```
<local-tx-datasource>
<jndi-name>customerDS</jndi-name>
<use-java-context>false</use-java-context>    
<connection-url>jdbc:mysql:replication://master_ip_address:3306,slave_ip_address:3306/customer_v2_local?loadBalancePingTimeout=1500;loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=7000;autoReconnect=true;failOverReadOnly=true;roundRobinLoadBalance=true</connection-url> 

<driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver</driver-class>
```

It starts JBOSS successfully. but geetting following **error at runtime**.

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'lkpmenuopt0_.SortOrder' in 'field list'com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.M
ySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'lkpmenuopt0_.SortOrder' in 'field list'
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedMySQLConnection.execSQL(LoadBalancedMySQLConnection.java:155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2119)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2281)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:342)

        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:209)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1811)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:258)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2233)
 [wrapped] org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2236)

>>org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; nested exception is org
.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
>>org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
[SQL: 1054, 42S22]
>>com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'lkpmenuopt0_.SortOrder' in 'field list
'
>>      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>>      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>>      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>>      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>>      at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>>      at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>>      at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
>>      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3597)
>>      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3529)
>>      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1990)
>>      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2151)
>>      at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2625)
>>      at com.mysql.jdbc.LoadBalancedMySQLConnection.execSQL(LoadBalancedMySQLConnection.java:155)
```

...

...

**And if remove word relication  from : `<connection-url>jdbc:mysql:replication:`
It working with NO runtime exception, but all read / write request goes to master only.**

Any hint to solve this issue ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`<connection-url>`jdbc:mysql:replication://master:3306,slave:3306/Customerdb?
loadBalancePingTimeout=1500`&amp;`loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=7000`&amp;`autoReconnect=true`&amp;`failOverReadOnly=true`&amp;`roundRobinLoadBalance=true`</connection-url>`

```
<connection-url>jdbc:mysql:replication://master:3306,slave:3306/Customerdb?loadBalancePingTimeout=1500&amp;loadBalanceBlacklistTimeout=7000&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;failOverReadOnly=true&amp;roundRobinLoadBalance=true</connection-url>
```

**finally this This works for me separating properties with `&amp;`